# Can we Test a Vaadin application with Selenium and cucumber?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, vaadin7, cucumber-jvm

i have to Test a Vaadin application with cucumber and Selenium web driver(using Java script Executor).is it a good approach for vaadin application Testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use Selenium and cucumber but you need to manage your framework to handle multiple windows and using Event firing and event listener classes.

My understanding of Vaadin application in which a UI is a viewport running in a web page. A web page can actually have multiple such UIs within it. Such situation is typical especially with portlets in a portal
--So your framework or test should handle multiple windows.
-- Need to handle Vaadin Sessions.
Vaadin follows an event-driven programming paradigm, in which events, and listeners that handle the events, are the basis of handling user interaction in an application

You need to have good knowledge of Selenium to automate Vaadin

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to test a Vaadin application using only Selenium. However, it might be better to use [Vaadin Testbench](https://vaadin.com/testbench)Vaadin. Testbench is based on Selenium, but provides better integration with Vaadin. The main advantages are:
1. There is no need to provide manual delays between actions, because it waits for UI Components to load.
2. It provides additional selectors to select Vaadin components.
3. It can provide screenshots of failed tests.

The only downside is that Testbench is a commercial feature that requires you to pay money.

For a more detailed analysis of pros/cons is see: [Official Blog Entry](https://vaadin.com/blog/testing-vaadin-applications-with-selenium-vs-testbench)

There is a [Github repository](https://github.com/rogozinds/testbenchtests) that shows a basic setup of testbench as well as plain Selenium.

Comment: it did not work on map Components , Since the maps are Canvas , we can not get the Element Locators on The Maps (this is one Con)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have same problem, and I used the Selenium IDE for identifying the `XPATH` for each element in vaadin, then use it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='thalamusboapp-218829419']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/span") );
```